# Что делать с вопросами с "плохим" кодом?

Tags: обсуждение, вопросы, новички

Наткнулся на [вопрос](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1506351/%d0%9f%d0%be%d1%87%d0%b5%d0%bc%d1%83-%d1%87%d0%b8%d1%81%d0%bb%d0%be-%d0%b2-%d0%b8%d0%b3%d1%80%d0%b5-2048-%d0%bf%d0%b5%d1%80%d0%b5%d0%bf%d1%80%d1%8b%d0%b3%d0%b8%d0%b2%d0%b0%d0%b5%d1%82-%d1%81%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%b7%d1%83-%d0%bd%d0%b0-%d1%81%d0%bb%d0%b5%d0%b4%d1%83%d1%8e%d1%89%d1%83%d1%8e-%d1%87%d0%b0%d1%81%d1%82%d1%8c-%d0%b0-%d0%bd%d0%b5-%d0%b7%d0%b0%d0%b4%d0%b5%d1%80%d0%b6%d0%b8%d0%b2%d0%b0%d0%b5). В этом вопросе есть описание проблемы.

**НО:** в вопросе содержится **трудночитаемый** код.

Минусовать такой вопрос вроде как неправильно (качество низкое не у вопроса, а у кода), закрывать - тоже (та же причина). Что делать?

Я решил оставить несколько комментариев, старался быть повежливей. Но есть такое чувство, что я поступил как-то неправильно, и из-за старания быть повежливей написал не то, что следовало.

Вот комментарии под вопросом:

> Я: 1) Переменные следует называть говорящими именами... 2) А в данном случае лучше использовать массив, а то код не очень.... Красивый

Это я так намекнул, что с кодом что-то не так, и  в тоже время объяснил, что стоит использовать массив (это не относилось к решению вопроса, но сделало бы код более читаемым, а поскольку автор работает с потоками, то должен знать, что такое массив)

> Автор вопроса: @Зонтик Спасибо. Жаль мне это не поможет с решением проблемы. Предпологаю что возможно дело в работе потоков, и код просто складывает два времени и сразу отрабатывает весь код.

> Я: Мне кажется, в вопрос стоит добавить метод arena()

Попросил автора добавить в вопрос код одного метода (без него трудно что-то сказать)

> Я: И кстати, рекомендую ознакомиться с [Как создать минимальный, самодостаточный и воспроизводимый пример?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Отправляю автора на страницу в справке.

> Автор вопроса: @Зонтик добавил

Автор вопроса говорит, что добавил метод arena() в вопрос

#### Дополнение

Я предложил правку, в которой поправил отступы, так код стал хотя бы немного читаемым.

Comment: Ничего там (особенно после такого ответа в комментарии, показывающего, что "это диагноз") делать не надо. Поставить минус и делу конец

Comment: Мне очень нравится статья про [ниндзя код](https://learn.javascript.ru/ninja-code). Возможно, автор как раз пытается пройти по пути ниндзя )

Comment: Отступы это нормально, я постоянно их поправляю (ну и в питоне без них никуда, да ^^). Это основные мои правки, исправления в блоках кода. / Я не считаю, что поставить здесь минус как-то плохо. Напомню, какая там подсказка: _Вопрос не отражает стремления разобраться; **он непонятен** или не несёт пользы_.

Comment: Ну и да, за это время там появился [хороший комментарий](//ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1506351#comment2702459_1506351).